# Pulling Array from PHP SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, json, indexing, simplexml, php-7.1

I want to pull an array out of a PHP SimpleXmlElement.
The original SimpleXMLElement is structured like below:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[226]
  public 'GetLeadDetailResponse' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[239]
      public 'GetLeadDetailResult' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[240]
          public 'LeadStat' => 
            array (size=4294)
```

The xmlElement is stored in a vairable called `$parser` and I want to get all the way down to 'LeadStat' so I indexed with:

```
$leadStatInfo = $parser->GetLeadDetailResponse->GetLeadDetailResult;
```

Which returns me this object:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[4534]
  public 'LeadStat' => 
    array (size=4294)
      0 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[240]
          public 'AdvertiserName' => string 'Modn Grp' (length=12)
          public 'AdvertiserId' => string '4539234' (length=6)
          public 'Timestamp' => string '2017-08-14T15:23:28.91' (length=22)
          public 'Type' => string 'Conversation' (length=15)
          public 'VisitId' => string '1442535353670' (length=9)
          public 'Attempt' => string '0' (length=1)
          public 'AgentName' => string 'Jack A' (length=6)
          public 'CustomerName' => string 'John Harris' (length=11)
          public 'CustomerEmail' => string 'harris@modn.com' (length=25)
          public 'CustomerPhone' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[4535]
              ...
          public 'CustomerAddress' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[4536]
              ...
          public 'NumberOfMessages' => string '12' (length=2)
      1 => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[4533]
          public 'AdvertiserName' => string 'Modn Grp' (length=12)
          public 'AdvertiserId' => string '4539234' (length=6)
          public 'Timestamp' => string '2017-08-14T17:21:11.157' (length=23)
          public 'Type' => string 'Conversation' (length=15)
          public 'VisitId' => string '37836763725' (length=9)
          public 'Attempt' => string '0' (length=1)
          public 'CustomerAddress' => 
            object(SimpleXMLElement)[4536]
              ...
          public 'NumberOfMessages' => string '0' (length=1)
      more elements...
```

Now I would like to get the `LeadStat` array and json_encode it so I have tried the following:

```
json_encode($leadStatInfo->LeadStat)
```

This unfortunately only returned one object instead of all the objects in the array.

```
{
  "AdvertiserName":"Modn Grp",
  "AdvertiserId":"4539234",
  "Timestamp":"2017-08-14T15:23:28.91",
  "Type":"Conversation",
  "VisitId":"1442535353670",
  "Attempt":"0",
  "AgentName":"Jack A",
  "CustomerName":"John Harris",
  "CustomerEmail":"harris@modn.com",
  "CustomerPhone":{},
  "CustomerAddress":{},
  "NumberOfMessages":"12"
}
```

**How do I pull out the full array?**

Is this because the objects in the array don't have the same attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SimpleXML, the `$leadStatInfo->LeadStat` is not really an array, but an iterable element. To get all the items in `LeadStat`you need to iterate over it.

```
$leadStatArray = array();
foreach($leadStatInfo->LeadStat as $leadStat) {
    $leadStatArray[] = $leadStat;
}
json_encode($leadStatArray);
```

Comment: Ahhh I see. I was bamboozled by the fake array. Thank you, my app works as intended now.